# How to install Remastersys?

Tags: software-installation, remastersys

I want to install Remastersys, but I get the following error:

```
$ sudo apt-get install remastersys  
Reading package lists... Done  
Building dependency tree  
Reading state information... Done  
E: Unable to locate package remastersys
```

Searching for Remastersys in Software Center also doesn't give proper results:

[image: remastersys search on USC]

I have tried [following these instructions](http://bikramkawan.com.np/how-to-install-remastersys-on-ubuntu-11-10-oneiric-ocelot/) and have added Software Sources as shown in the following screenshot, but I still get the same error:

[image: software sources]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use remastersys.

http://www.remastersys.com/ubuntu.html

Please read the instruction carefully.

1. In Firefox, go to :

   http://www.remastersys.com/ubuntu/remastersys.gpg.key.

   save file as text someplace where you can find it.
2. In synaptic, go to Settings/Repositories; select `Authentication` tab and `Import Key File` just downloaded.
3. Still in synaptic, go to `Other Software` tab and click `Add`, then enter the apt 
   line

   `deb http://www.remastersys.com/ubuntu oneiric main`
4. **After adding it, a new apt line will automatically added ended with `Source`. You need to uncheck it**
5. Leave the repositories tab and "Reload".
6. Search for `remastersys` and select for install.  Edit/Apply Marked Changes.

Comment: this didn't work, I'll update the question with details.

Comment: This solution correctly shows loading an **Oneiric** (Ubuntu 11.10) key, but your screen shots show **Karmic** (Ubuntu 9.10) sources.

Comment: sure.  Well I am definitely running 11.10 so tried again but still not working and stuck.

Comment: don't use `geekconnection` url. Use remastersys url as posted in the link. And don't forget to uncheck `source` line.

Comment: try donwloading `all` debs from this url - http://www.remastersys.com/downloads/ . You have to take care of dependencies if any.