# How can I make a live-usb without downloading the ISO file?

Tags: live-usb, iso

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I create a .iso (USB) of my current system?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/146431/how-can-i-create-a-iso-usb-of-my-current-system)

Is there a way to create a live-usb without downloading the iso files from the internet. Actually, I am using lubuntu on my PC but I don't have the `ISO` with me anymore; so I wanted to know how can I create a `live-usb` from the installed OS(Lubuntu) on my System.

I am trying to avoid downloading the `iso`file.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There is probably no way that can be done, at least in the present scenario. You either need to download the iso from the internet or buy a CD/DVD/USB, which can be procured at very low prices, even for free, though officially Canonical has stopped shipping them to your home for free.

Answer (score 0):

Even with the Ubuntu Startup Disk Creator you need to download the ISO. There is no way to make a live-USB without the ISO.