# Can I generate an installation CD image from my current installation? How do I clone an Ubuntu install?

Tags: disk-image, cloning

I recently upgraded my installation of 13.04 to 13.10. My friend has seen this and would like to install Ubuntu.

Is there any way I can generate an installation CD from my current install without just downloading the ISO so that we can do a install on my friend's computer?

Comment: See I was using ubuntu 13.04 vs in my system and then I update my system os ubuntu 13.10 by the fooloing commands:  sudo apt-get update and then do-release-upgrade -d.Now one of my friend wants the new 13.10version of ubuntu form me.So I wanted to generate .iso image of ubuntu 13.10 form my system so that he can also install 13.10version of ubuntu in his system

Comment: @Subho you should revise your question then to specifically explain that you're trying to create an image of your system so you can install an exact duplicate of your system on another system.

Answer (score 3):

1) You could clone / ghost the drive with `dd` like [this.](http://www.backuphowto.info/linux-backup-hard-disk-clone-dd)

```
dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb
```

2) Another option [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/clonezilla-live-doc.php)

Example usages:

- Save disk image
- Restore disk image
- Disk to disk clone (Same as the above `dd` command)
- One image to multiple disks
- Create Recovery Clonezilla

3) Other possibilities based on `dpkg` and `rsync` and a fresh install [like here.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9135/best-way-to-backup-all-settings-list-of-installed-packages-tweaks-etc) Probably more preferable due to hardware/user info/passwords, as has been indicated in other answers.

Create text file of current packages as seen [(here)](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReinstallingSamePackages):

```
sudo -i  # starts a root session
    # ... run whatever commands you need to mount the safe storage device ...
dpkg --get-selections > /<path to safe storage device>/dpkg-selections
    # records a list of installed packages into the file named after the > sign.
    # ... now run commands you need to safely unmount the storage device ...
<ctrl-D>  # end the root session.
```

Move the file created from this to the friends computer and run the following:

```
sudo -i # starts a root session.
    # ... commands to mount the storage device ...
dpkg --set-selections < /<path to safe storage device>/dpkg-selections
    # sets the list of packages to install from the list kept previously
apt-get dselect-upgrade # actually installs the packages.
    # ... now unmount the device ...
<ctrl-D>  # end the root session
```

Answer (score 2):

While you *can* create an image of your system, it's not a great idea. Any ISO you create and give him would include lots of things that might cause problems, like user passwords, wireless networks, driver settings, etc.

A much better idea would be for you to download the official 13.10 installation ISO, burn it to a DVD, and give him that.

Or if he is already running an older version of Ubuntu, he can run the exact same commands you did to upgrade to 13.10.

Comment: Also, if you installed a bunch of packages that are not default you might be able to install the same packages by creating a file with all of the packages that you have on your system [(like this)](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReinstallingSamePackages). So you would install 13.10 on friends computer and follow the procedure for duplicating the packages only.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a tool that can create an ISO of your current Ubuntu state,  I would recommend using the [remastersys](https://askubuntu.com/a/146433/189471).
Else if your trying to clone your Ubuntu to another PC try this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2724/best-way-to-clone-an-installation-copying-to-identical-hardware).

Comment: Could you provide instruction on how to use remastersys?