# How to create bootable ISO from an installed OS?

Tags: boot, system-installation, usb, iso

Say I have two systems A and B.

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 on system A and need same set of settings in system B, for which I am thinking to make a bootable iso from System A(creating as a backup). so that I can make Live USB from the generated iso and boot the System B which will be now the replica of System A.

Could you please tell is there any method or tool in doing this process?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I generate an installation CD image from my current installation? How do I clone an Ubuntu install?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/384392/can-i-generate-an-installation-cd-image-from-my-current-installation-how-do-i-c)

Comment: Or http://askubuntu.com/questions/2724/best-way-to-clone-an-installation-copying-to-identical-hardware?lq=1

Answer (score 2):

You have many tools that are available for Ubuntu 12.04(some of them are not used anymore for newer versions. but still works for ubuntu 12.04).

- relinux
- remastersys
- Ubuntu Builder
- System Imager

And much more.

I personally advise you to use Relinux.

Download this version from [launchpad](https://launchpad.net/relinux/0.3/0.3.0a2/+download/relinux_0.3.0a2.tar.gz) and not the last version to use the following tutorial on it

[Here](http://www.howtoforge.com/creating-your-own-distributable-ubuntu-dvd-relinux) is a great tutorial how to use.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Clonezilla. It's a great tool if you want all systems have a same copy of OS and softwares. As your requirement look like you want all alike systems. You can clone any hard disk partition or full hard disk using this utility.

You will have a great choice of USB install, network install, samba server, etc. to install your cloned image to other system.
Visit this tutorial to learn about "Use Clonezilla Live to clone a computer’s internal hard drive to a USB external drive".

Get Steps [here](http://www.geekyprojects.com/cloning/how-to-use-clonezilla-tutorial/)!

Answer (score 0):

Many of the tools that were viable when this question was first posted [have become abandonware](https://raywoodcockslatest.wordpress.com/2021/08/17/linux-v2p/#ILa).

Clonezilla is an enduring option. Some (including me) find it cumbersome and sometimes confusing. Systemback is more user-friendly. There are multiple tutorials for both. Distroshare is another option. There are also [paid options](https://raywoodcockslatest.wordpress.com/2021/08/17/linux-v2p/#EPa) that I have not tried (e.g., TeraByte, possibly PowerISO).

I will mention some other possibilities, in case the ISO route is not really your best solution.

First, I suggest thinking of backup and copying as two separate processes. Backup should occur regularly -- maybe monthly, if you don't make many changes to your system drive. Your best backup method may or may not be the same as your copying method.

For copying, there are at least three basic approaches:

1. Connect drive B directly to drive A. This is feasible, even on laptops, if you can get drive B out of its machine: you can connect it to system A using an external docking station (assisted by male-female SATA extension cord if necessary).
2. Start with an image of drive A. You may or may not find that the imaging process gives you the kind of monthly backup you want. Use the image to restore the system to drive B.
3. Make an ISO of drive A. The ISO will function as you say: install it onto a USB drive, boot system B with that, and use that to install onto drive B.

There is [further information](https://raywoodcockslatest.wordpress.com/2021/08/17/linux-v2p/) on those possibilities, in case the ISO route is not, after all, the one you want.