# Turn .vmwarevm into .iso

Tags: boot, server, vmware, iso

I was wondering if anyone knows how to take the `.vmwarevm`and the files inside it and turn it into an `.iso`. I searched on Google but haven't found anything.

It would be amazing if the `.iso` can simulate a first boot whenever someone opens it as well.

I want to turn my customized Ubuntu Mini 15.04 64-bit into an `.iso`. Right now it is a VMware workstation (`.vmwarevm`).

[Cross posted on Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/213439/turn-vmwarevm-into-iso)

Comment: Please do not crosspost: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/213439/turn-vmwarevm-into-iso

Comment: Sorry, won't do it again.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create bootable ISO from an installed OS?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/642978/how-to-create-bootable-iso-from-an-installed-os)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you'll find such tool, eventhough you can convert the `.vmwarevm` to `.iso` this doesn't mean this `iso` will be used as live cd or installation cd. I really don't know why you want to do that?!

Instead you have the  option to create a Live CD of your running system in Ubuntu, you have many number of tools that give you the ability to create live CD of your running machine. Please take a look on my answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/642979/150504

Comment: I don't have a GUI, just command line. Is it still possible?

Comment: use relinux from the answer linked, it's used in CLI mode

Comment: @c.C You are welcome, wish you the best