# How get a bootable ISO image, simply

Tags: boot, system-installation, virtualbox, iso

I have Kubuntu 16.10 virtualized with VirtualBox (host PclinuxOs) and I'd like to get a bootable ISO of it.

I tried PinguyBuilder, but the ISO image is not bootable with virtualbox. (After 7/8 sec, it freezes.)

I tried genisoimage via terminal, but I don't know how exclude some folders (like `/media/sf_*`).

Can you help me? Thank you

Comment: You are asking about a method - to create an iso image. I am asking about what you want - the end result. How would you use that image? It is difficult to create an iso image. Maybe there is another method, that would bring you what you want. For example, if you want to run the image in VirtualBox in another computer, you can simply copy the vdi file (or make a compressed copy of it).

Comment: Have you considered just cloning the drive using an approach like [this?](http://askubuntu.com/a/586172/225694)

Comment: Do you test such applications like remastersys, relinux , ubuntu-builder and Ubuntu Customization Kit  ?

Comment: @sudodus: I want masterize that iso and install (kubunti) on (many) pc.

Comment: @Elder Geek: I am not interested in cloning a drive, but I want get an iso image to masterize and install on other pc.

Comment: A cloned copy of an installed linux system is portable between computers, if you avoid proprietary drivers. It is possible but much more difficult to create an iso file complete with an installer. Please try with the tools suggested by @ali. Be prepared for a bumpy road. Good luck  :-)

Comment: @duns I'm sorry to hear that you are unhappy with my recommendation. It's been my experience that far more people are successful with the approach I recommended than the one you are set upon. The key here is in your title. The word simply. To put it plainly, It's not simple. However, take a look at [this related post](http://askubuntu.com/questions/642978/how-to-create-bootable-iso-from-an-installed-os?rq=1) if you are intent on following this path and you have my best wishes for future success.